# filling listbox with textfile

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, streamreader

So I'm trying to fill a listbox with names that I have put into a txt file.
When I use Console.WriteLine(naam), it actually shows the names in the file but I just can't get them into the listbox. Does anyone know a solution for this problem? Thanks in adventage.

```
public void PopulateList( ListBox list, string file)
{
        string naam;
        string sourcepath =  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments); 
        string myfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcepath, file);
        StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(myfile);
        naam = reader.ReadLine();
        while (naam != null)
        {
            list.Items.Add(naam);
            list.Items.Add(Environment.NewLine);
            naam = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I've found a solution it was just a dumb mistake..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please use MVVM for developing any wpf application. This is not good to manipulate UI controls in code behind like this. Use proper binding.

If I had to solve this problem, I would create the collections of strings like

```
 public ObservableCollection<string> Names { get; set; }
```

and bind it to the ListBox like

```
 <ListBox x:Name="NamesListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Names}"/>
```

Then in my Window's constructor I would initialize Names and set the DataContext of Window and update the PopulateList method like below:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Names = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        DataContext = this;
        PopulateList("C:\names.txt");
    }

    public void PopulateList(string file)
    {
        string naam;
        string sourcepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        string myfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcepath, file);
        StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(myfile);
        naam = reader.ReadLine();
        while (naam != null)
        {
            Names.Add(naam);
            naam = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133338/loading-a-listbox-from-a-file)

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("youfilePath");
string line = string.Empty;
try
{
    //Read the first line of text
    line = sr.ReadLine();
    //Continue to read until you reach end of file
    while (line != null)
    {
        list.Items.Add(line);
        //Read the next line
        line = sr.ReadLine();
    }

    //close the file
    sr.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
}
finally
{
    //close the file
    sr.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `File.ReadLines` you can use to make this a bit nicer:

```
string sourcepath =  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments); 
string myfile = Path.Combine(sourcepath, file);

var items = File.ReadAllLines(myfile)
    .Select(line => new ListItem(line));

List.Items.AddRange(items);
```